# Upgrading to 32GB RAM for Mac mini Server (MD389LL/A)

Tags: upgrade, memory, mac-mini

I'm using a Mac mini Server (Late 2012) with 2,3 GHz Intel Core i7 processor and 16GB RAM. This type of processor (Intel® Core™ i7-3615QM) supports a max memory size of 32GB. Look at specification: [Here](http://ark.intel.com/products/64900/Intel-Core-i7-3615QM-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_30-GHz).

Is it possible to upgrade RAM in my Mac mini to 32GB (for instance a Crucial Kit 2x16GB)?

I understand that Apple has to update Memory Reference Code in the firmware of the Mac mini but maybe exists another way to upgrade a memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. That Mac mini is limited to 16 GB max ram.

You can be pretty sure that if it's not mentioned in [Everymac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-i7-2.3-late-2012-server-specs.html) or sold by [OWC[MacSales]](https://eshop.macsales.com/upgrades/mac-mini-late-2012-2.3-ghz-with-lion-server/memory) or ramjet.com, it can't be done. These reputable sellers will always provide good research and advice if more memory can be used past Apple official specifications.

Whether you would choose them as your vendor or not, they tend to cover all possibilities & often support things that Apple never intended.

Answer (score 2):

Anyway, I'm afraid I have some **bad news** for people hoping for more than 16 GB total memory.

Due to an intel Core i hardware design defect, seems to have been fixed only for 4th or 5th generation Core i processors, the previous generations won't take 16GB DDR3 modules although the parameters for such modules were established within the original DDR3 specs.

So, it should work, but it doesn't.

Intel's fault.

Sorry.

Comment: I don't recall having read on everymac or OWC that my Intel HD3000 VRAM could be boosted to 2GB. Yet, it can be done, it's wide open on the net. I did.

Comment: Do you have a source for the Intel design defect?  I'd be interesting in reading more.

Comment: I did a lot of research trying to get my own Mac mini running 32GB... somehow I hit this Anandtech article and from it I could dig a little further and confirm what they said.

https://www.anandtech.com/show/7742/im-intelligent-memory-to-release-16gb-unregistered-ddr3-modules

Comment: "The JEDEC specifications for DDR3 do account for the use of 8 Gbit packages (either one 8 Gbit die or two 4 Gbit dies per package), should these be available.  However I am told that currently there is a fundamental non-fixable issue on all Intel processors (except Avoton and Rangeley, other Silvermont (BayTrail) is affected) that means that these dies are not recognised."

Interesting stuff! Have fun!

Comment: Another excerpt: " With a 4 Gbit package, to access the row, all 16 are used (A0 to A15), whereas a column uses 10 (A0 to A9).  In the 8 Gbit package, the column also requires A11, all part of the JEDEC spec.  This works on Avoton/Rangeley, but not on any other Intel processor, according to Intelligent Memory, and the exact nature of the issue is down to Intel’s implementation of the specification."

Well, my understanding of "Intel’s implementation of the specification" is simply "Intel's faulty design". They simply didn't implement the DDR3 specification entirely until too late.